# Run .java file directly using cmd on Mac Terminal

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

I have a folder consisting some .java files. Instead of building a new java project, I run one of the .java files hellowworld.java using terminal:

```
java hellowworld
```

But it gives me could not find or load main class helloworld. What should I do?

Comment: Have you compiled the class?

Comment: Yes, it says: Class names, 'hellowworld', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Comment: You're missing the `.java` suffix in the compile command

Comment: Yes.. that's exactly what the problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile it first with

```
javac hellowworld.java
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler

Comment: It says: Class names, 'hellowworld', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Comment: According to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/ that means you forgot to put '.java' in the command.

Comment: @Meteorite If this answer helps, please click on the checkmark that you see to the left of it.